# asp.net GridView rows are not clickable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to create a asp.net GridView that represents employees, and if the user clicks on a row, it will show the full details of the employee. I created one, but the rows (beside delete button) are not clickable. how to make them clickable?

this is the design code:

```
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceMain" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AtidConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [first_name], [last_name] FROM [Contacs]" 
                    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Contacs] WHERE [ID] = @ID" 
                    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Contacs] ([ID], [first_name], [last_name]) VALUES (@ID, @first_name, @last_name)" 
                    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Contacs] SET [first_name] = @first_name, [last_name] = @last_name WHERE [ID] = @ID">
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="String" />
                    </DeleteParameters>
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="first_name" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="last_name" Type="String" />
                    </InsertParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="first_name" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="last_name" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="String" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox7" runat="server" />
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
                    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
                    CellPadding="4" 
                    DataKeyNames="ID" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceMain"  
                    ForeColor="#333333" Height="256px" PageSize="20" 
                    style="margin-left: 240px; margin-right: 53px; margin-top: 1px" 
                    Width="517px" OnRowCommand="delete_button_Click" 
                    OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnDataBound="fun">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" 
                            SortExpression="id" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="first_name" HeaderText="first name" 
                            SortExpression="first_name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="last_name" HeaderText="last name" 
                            SortExpression="last_name" />
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle Height="15px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
                        Height="10px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox8" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: What you mean by grid cells are not clickable?

Comment: yes. the grid cells are not clickable.

Comment: Make sure you haven't marked the cells `ReadOnly`.

Comment: there are not read only.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET GridView control is not that advanced but it's doable using client-side code as detailed [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Selecting-GridView-Row-by-clicking-anywhere-on-the-Row.aspx).

Basically you generate a client-side click event (posted from the article):

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
    }
}
```

This example clicks the row, but really you can trigger whatever action you want. Using "Select$" is the default way to trigger select event; you can also trigger RowCommand too (I believe) with any event.

Comment: I did it. but the "OnRowDataBound" function is only call at the beginning of the running, not when clicking. the rows are still not clickable.

Comment: This function renders out the client-side click event to the row, and triggers a postback to process on the server.  View the source of the page and verify the onclick is attached to the tr element.

Comment: there is no tr element in the page.

Comment: Are you sure?  The Grid is all about tables.  Could you post the markup of a GridView row?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new in asp.net. where in code is the markup of a GridView row?

Comment: The GridView is a server side control.  All it does is render HTML in the browser.  It's the HTML in the browser that you want to inspect. Run in the browser, right-click and view source.  Find the HTML markup for the TR tag for the grid, and it should have an onclick. If it doesn't, then this attribute isn't being added.  If it is, there is another problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81757/discussion-between-zag-gol-and-brian-mains).